# Getting nested JSON output from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations

Suppose I have a Rails app with two models `Post` and `Comment`. A post `has_many` comments and a comment `belongs_to` a post.
How can I override the `respond_to` function in the `show` action in order to get a JSON response containing both the `Post` properties and an array of `Comment` objects that it has?

Currently it is the vanilla Rails default:

```
# posts_controller.rb
def show
  @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @post }
  end
 end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using Active Record serialization method.

```
to_json
```

Below code should work.

```
 format.json { render json: @post.to_json(:include => :comments) }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [active_model_serializers](https://github.com/josevalim/active_model_serializers) for json serialization.  It is easy to include associated objects and also separates things by having a different file for serialization.

Example:

```
class PostSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :id, :title, :body
    has_many :comments
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override `to_json` in model or you can use [Jbuilder](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder) or [rabl](http://railscasts.com/episodes/322-rabl).

Answer (score 1):

Rails has provide the best way to respond :

Define **respond_to** on the top of your controller . like :

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :xml, :json

  def show
    @post = current_user.posts.find(params[:id])
    respond_with (@post)
  end
end
```

For more info take a look on : http://davidwparker.com/2010/03/09/api-in-rails-respond-to-and-respond-with/